# "Squeezing lemma" for tubolar neighborhoods

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

During the proof of the fact that every smooth submanifold $N \subset R^n$ has a tubolar neighborhood, I need to prove that there is a smooth function $f: N \mapsto \mathbb{R}^+$ that "squeezes" the tubolar nbhd into an open set $U$ such that the map $g:(p,v) \mapsto p+v$ is an embedding from $U$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now, I get why this works locally ($dg_{(p,0)}$ is the identity, if I am not mistaken), but I would like to see a relatively rigorous proof that this "squeezing function" is smooth and more important that $g$ restricted to $U$ is an embedding. Again, this sounds obvious given how $g$ is defined, but I would like to see a sufficiently rigorous proof.

EDIT: As pointed out, it should be explained why I bother searching for such $f$. The fact is that $g$ is an embedding if you restrict yourself on a sufficiently small neighborhood $U$ of $N$ seen into its normal bundle. The squeezing function is required to embed $\nu N$ into $U$ leaving $N$ fixed. This way I’d have that $g \circ f$ is an embedding of $\nu N$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ that is also an open nbhd of $N$ and leaves $N$ fixed, so it is a tubolar nbhd.

Comment: You have not explained where $f$ comes into the story.

Comment: @TedShifrin I have edited the question, hope it’s more clear now.

Comment: No, you certainly don't mean $g\circ f$. The issue is that when $N$ is non-compact, you can't necessarily choose an $\epsilon$-neighborhood globally. If $N$ spirals tighter, the $\epsilon$ needs to shrink. $f$ is going to control the radius $\epsilon$ as you move around $N$. At any rate, I'll suggest that, like most situations in manifold theory, that you think about using a partition of unity subordinate to an appropriate covering of $N$ in order to define your $f$.

Comment: Yeah, I meant that the $\epsilon$ varies smoothly, I don’t want a global $\epsilon$ neighborhood, I want to choose this $\epsilon$ smoothly so that everything works. With $f$ I mean this global squeezing function that works. So you are suggestting to squeeze things locally and then use a partition of the unity to glue everything together?

Comment: I figured it out. You really just have to take an adequate atlas and use a partition of unity on the counterimages of the open sets (which I suppose to be small enough to be trivialising). I could carry out the details in a more precise answer, if someone is interested.